# Trying to call a method (a custom sql update method) in .net from jquery but im getting errors such as 404 and 500

Tags: jquery, html, sql, ajax

I am trying to call the .net method from a JavaScript file in a Web Form project, I am unsure if I am doing things correctly and I am struggling to debug.

.net method:

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static void UpdateDatabase(string location, string content)
    {
        string connectionString = @"Server=DESKTOP-JFCN2O9\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Opticron;User Id=website;Password=Popcorn99!";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [dbo].[Content] SET [ContentData] = " + content + "WHERE [ContentLoc] = " + location);

        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        command.Connection = connection;

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();

    }
```

JavaScript file:

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {

$('.editBtn').click(function () {
    $(this).closest("tr").find(".contentInput").removeAttr('readOnly');
    $(this).closest("td").find(".saveBtn").removeAttr('hidden');


})

$('.saveBtn').click(function () {
    var changedContent = $(this).closest("tr").find(".contentInput").val();
    var locOfChange = $(this).closest("tr").find(".loc").text();

    $.ajax({
        url: '../../WebForm1.aspx/UpdateDatabase',
        method: 'post',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: '{location:' + locOfChange + ', content:' + changedContent + '}',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function () {
            alert("success")
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error)
        }
    })


    $(this).closest("tr").find(".contentInput").attr('readonly')
    $(this).closest("td").find(".saveBtn").attr('hidden');
})
```

});

I am expecting the database to be updated and the web page to be adjusted as expected... there shouldn't be any issue with the database as i am using a select function in the load of the page and that works correctly.

Addon info : Errors :
when i load the page everything loads up but i get this error - 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

when i click on the saveBtn i get this error - 
jquery.js:9600 POST https://localhost:44341/WebForm1.aspx/UpdateDatabase 500

Answer (score 0):

Your update SQL statement is malformed. Missing spaces and quotes around strings.

Change:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [dbo].[Content] 
SET [ContentData] = " + content + "WHERE [ContentLoc] = " + location);
```

To:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [dbo].[Content] 
SET [ContentData] = '" + content + "' WHERE [ContentLoc] = '" + location + "');
```

Share the actual error that you are getting, if this does not fix all your issues.
Are you getting the location and content correctly?

Comment: Yes the location and content have both been put into an alert to ensure they are correct and they are... however this is only done in jquery and i am unsure if they are received in correct format and such... but i am unsure how to check that.

Comment: Can you not debug the service? On top of the malformed update SQL the only other thing I see wrong is the format of data being passed to the service.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to Nawed Khan

Solution:

I had to add double quotation marks around my sql and json attributes :

```
data: '{location:' + locOfChange + ', content:' + changedContent + '}',
```

to

```
data: '{location: "' + locOfChange + '", content: "' + changedContent + '"}',
```

and

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [dbo].[Content] SET [ContentData] = " + content + "WHERE [ContentLoc] = " + location);
```

to

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [dbo].[Content] SET[ContentData] = '" + content + "' WHERE[ContentLoc] = '" + location + "'");
```